# Firefox - strange behaviour with SVG transform, mask and dashed line

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I've got this inline SVG on my site

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrpb6p15/)

Problem seems to be somewhere around this line.

```
<line
  x1="25%" y1="-567"
  x2="25%" y2="200%"
  style="stroke-dasharray:6 11;"
  transform="skewY(45)" />
```

On different versions of Firefox I see some glitches with missing or flicking parts of image. In chrome/edge everything is OK. Am I using some non-standard SVG stuff, or it's just some FF bug? And is there any workarounds?

Comment: What versions? What operating systems?

Comment: Windows 7/FF 47; Windows 10/FF 48 - problem exists. Archlinux/FF 40 - no problem.

Comment: report it as a bug to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: Done: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292090